# QuickBook Enterprise 12 API with IPP DevKit version 2.0

Tags: quickbooks

Summary :-
Will IPP DevKit Version 2.0 work with QuickBook Enterprise 12 Windows Desktop application.

i think it only work with online version of quickbook. Please confirm.

---

I am new to Quickbook development and want to develop the application that fetch the data from QuickBook Enterprise 12 Windows Desktop application. I founded SDK two that QBXML and QBFC, among these QBFC is a com component and with this i am able to fetch various table data.

But com this COM component have some limitation that we cannot fetch record with in chunks and other also.

So i search and found IPP DevKit Version 2.0 that provide the missing feature. But i am not sure weather this will work with QuickBook Enterprise 12 Windows Desktop application.

i think it only work with online version of quickbook. Please confirm.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my scenario QBFC is only choice. Because  Sync manager will first upload the data to intuit server and than provide data to me and its on end user choice to use Sync manager or not.

Answer (score 2):

The IPP DevKit 2.0 works with the QuickBooks V2 REST APIs for both QuickBooks Online and QuickBooks Desktop.

REST APIs: http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere

DevKit Docs: http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0055_DevKits/0100_IPP_.NET_DevKit

Comment: But be aware that IPP *only works for SaaS* applications (e.g. you're allowing your customers to connect their QuickBooks files to your app). If you're not SaaS, use QBFC or the COM components from the SDK.

Comment: QuickBooks V2 REST APIs will able to fetch data from my desktop Quickbook enterprise 12 edition. Please confirm and is there any sample code.

Comment: Correct. Sync manager is required... http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0300_Sync_Manager 
We have sample code available in GitHub... https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code
Please read our FAQs for supported application types... http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0058_FAQ